# SQL retrieval: Empty Dataframe in IDLE or Visual Studio Code but populated Dataframe in Jupyter Notes

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook

I am not a good python coder (beginner) so apologies if the code isn't up to pythonista's snuff!
Bit of a weird situation and I can not figure this out.  I have been wracking my brains trying to fix it out but can't seem to be able to.  I am sure it's a really simple fix I am overlooking...

The "allData" Dataframe is pulling data from an SQL database.  From that I am extracing a number of records and appending to the "managerListImput" empty dataframe.  I am iterating for a number of records specified and looking up the details for each one before appending.  It works in Jupyter notes and I get the desired output but when I run it in IDLE or Visual Studio Code I get an empty dataframe. Very frustrating. Hopefully someon can solve it....
Thanks in advance

Here's the code:

```
def selected():
   managerReturns = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['hName','Returns'])
   managerCount = int(input("how many MANAGERS do you want to use?  Enter a quantity: "))
   i=0
   while i < managerCount:        
       managerListData = allData[['hID','hName','Min_Date','Max_Date']]
       managerListFind = input('Enter partial or whole MANAGER name: ')
       managerList = managerListData[managerListData['hName'].str.contains(managerListFind, case=False)]
       managerList = managerList.drop_duplicates(subset=['hID'])
       managerList = managerList.set_index('hID')
       print(managerList)
       managerID = input('Pick/Type in an MANAGER list ID ("hID") From the List Above: ')
       managerName = managerListData.query('hID ==' + str(managerID))['hName']
       managerName = managerName.iloc[0] # otherwise you get a list of the same names
       manager = allData.query('hID == @managerID')

       manager = manager.filter(['hName','Returns'])  
       managerReturns = managerReturns.append(manager)
    
       i += 1

   managerReturns = managerReturns.groupby([managerReturns.index, 'hName'])['Returns'].mean().unstack()
   return managerReturns   

test31 = selected()
print(test31)
```

Output in IDLE or Visual Studio Code:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Output (in Jupyter Notes) i.e. the output I want!::

```
Date        Manager1    Manager2
4/1/2010    NaN         0.1459
5/1/2010    NaN         0.0049
6/1/2010    NaN        -0.0206
7/1/2010    NaN        -0.0416
8/1/2010    NaN         0.4537
...         ...         ...
7/1/2021    0.0056      0.0047
8/1/2021    0.0185     -0.0086
9/1/2021   -0.0269      0.0207
10/1/2021   0.0261     -0.0080
11/1/2021  -0.0256      0.0228
```

Comment: I see the <sql> tag, but there's no SQL at all above. Do you expect an SQL answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple: the `managerID` has to be turned into an integer, so I added this:

```
managerID = int(managerID)
```

I guess Jupyter Notes is smart enough to recognize it as a number.